# What is the correct way to select an element with a specific a class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I'm trying to use jQuery to select a div element but, for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to work.  I'm trying to set it up so when the user clicks on the `span` element with the class `remove` it finds the closest `div` element with the class `class-i-want-to-select`

This block of code is dynamically added after the page has finished loading:

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <span style="float:left;">some text</span>
      <span class="remove" style="float:right;">[X]</span> ///user clicks here
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   <div class="class-i-want-to-select"></div> ///want to select this element
</div>
```

This is the code i tried to use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    var that = $(this).closest('div').find('.class-i-want-to-select');
    console.log(that);
});
```

I figured the code above would properly select the element I'm trying the select but it's not working.  Am I doing something wrong?   Since the code block I'm  traversing is dynamically added, is there a different way I need to select it?

Comment: The problem is with the `.closest('div')`, which selects a div that does not contain the element you're looking for.  Try `.closest('.container')` instead.

Comment: add the class or unique Id to remove button dataset. 
<span class="remove" data-target="class-i-want-to-select">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: you are trying to get closest div and then finding class which will not give you the parent div having class `class-i...`
You need to put class selector `.container` in `closest` only and it will return the correct parent div, then call `find` on it to get `class-i-want-to-select`.  check below code

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('div.container');
    var that = $parent.find('div.class-i-want-to-select');
    console.log(that);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your span is wrapped in a div as well. So closest will find that div instead of the div with the class container. And that div does not have a child of class-i-want-to-select. So try using `.closest( '.container' )`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    var that = $(this).parent().parent().find('.class-i-want-to-select');
    console.log(that);
});
```

Comment: This works for the html given, but chaining multiple `.parent()` calls together like this isn't good practice. It ties the js too tightly to the exact HTML structure; any minor changes in the page layout will end up breaking the script.

Comment: accepted. I just tried to give an alternative answer to what others have given.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead with one of the container divs as its selector:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    var that = $(this).parents('.container').find('.class-i-want-to-select');
    console.log(that.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <span style="float:left;">some text</span>
      <span class="remove" style="float:right;">[X]</span> ///user clicks here
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   <div class="class-i-want-to-select">I am the one you want!</div> ///want to select this element
</div>
```